# Generalized Birman exact sequence for surfaces with boundaries

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-groups

Let $S_g^n$ be a surface of genus g with n boundaries and let $Mod(S_g^n)$ be its mapping class group.
We will also denote by $S_{g,m}^n$ a surface of genus g with n boundaries and m punctures.

The classical Birman exact sequence is

$$ 1 \to \pi_1(UT(S_g^{n-1}) \to Mod(S_g^n) \to Mod(S_g^{n-1}) \to 1$$

where $UT(S_g^{n-1})$ is the unitary tangent bundle over $S_g^{n-1}$ and the last map corresponds to capping one of the boundaries by a disk.

I am wondering what is the kernel of the map $f \colon Mod(S_g^n) \to Mod(S_g^{n-k})$ obtained by capping $k$ boundaries by $k$ disks.

It is a known fact, proven by Birman, that the kernel of the map $Mod(S_{g,m}) \to Mod(S_{g,m-k})$ obtained by forgetting $k$ punctures can be identified with $B_k(S_{g,m})$, the braid group on $k$ strands over $S_{g,m}$.

Therefore, if $PB_k(S_{g,m})$ is the pure braid group on $k$ strands over $S_{g,m}$, my best guess is that the kernel of $f$ is isomorphic to $PB_k(S_{g,m}) \oplus \mathbb{Z}^k$, where $\mathbb{Z}^k$ corresponds to the free abelian group with generators the Dehn twists around the boundaries we capped. Indeed, we can factor $f$ into $f = f_1f_2$ where $f_2$ caps the boundaries by punctures disks and $f_1$ forgets the punctures.

Is this correct? If so, is there another expression for this kernel? (Similarly to how $\pi_1(S_g^{n-1}) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ can be identified with $\pi_1(UT(S_g^{n-1})$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost right, your guess.

The easiest description is geometric, generalizing Birman's description $\pi_1(UT(S_g^{n-1}))$. You look instead at the configuration space parametrizing $k$ distinct points in $S_g^{n-k}$, together with unit tangent vectors at each of these $k$ points. So this is an open subspace of the cartesian product $UT(S_g^{n-k})^k$. The fundamental group of this space is the group you care about. It is sometimes called the *framed* braid group.

The framed braid group is an extension of the pure braid group $PB_k(S^m_g)$ by $\mathbf Z^k$, as one sees geometrically by fibering the framed configuration space over the usual configuration space with fiber $(S^1)^k$. For an open surface the tangent bundle is trivial, which implies that this $(S^1)^k$-bundle is trivial, and thus the extension is trivial, too. In this case your guess is correct. But for closed surfaces you get a nontrivial central extension.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Do you happen to know of a reference where this is proven?

Comment: Not off the top of my head (but it's probably my own ignorance of the literature). But if you think about these things geometrically it becomes pretty clear. The group $\mathrm{Mod}(S_{g,m}^n)$ is the fundamental group of the moduli orbifold parametrizing a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ with $n+m$ distinct ordered marked points and a unit tangent vector at the first $n$ points. The forgetful map in the Birman exact sequence is induced by a corresponding forgetful map of moduli orbifolds which is literally a fiber bundle...

Comment: ...and the fiber is the "framed configuration space" that I mentioned. And this framed configuration space is a $K(\pi,1)$ for the same reason that the usual configuration space of points in a surface is a $K(\pi,1)$. And the moduli orbifolds are $K(\pi,1)$'s, too, by Teichmuller theory. So the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of the fibration gives you what you want.

Comment: @DanPetersen in your last statement I think rather for a closed surface you get a non-split extension.

Comment: For a reference (also explaining the relation with the mapping class group) see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4471

Comment: @Adrien Thanks for the correction and the reference. Indeed I was writing nonsense (the fundamental group of the base does not act by monodromy on the *homotopy* groups of the fiber...)